# Adding an action to Magento shopping cart price rules

Tags: php, magento

I am looking to remove tax based on a product's selected custom option.
I want to have regular tax rules in place for my products. If, however, a visitor chooses option x from one of the custom options, then tax should not be applied.

I have considered using configurable products for this where the simple product representing the tax free option would not have taxes, but magento calculates taxes based on the parent product for configurable products.

Given [this article](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-shopping-cart-promotion-rule-for-product-with-custom-options/), I can create custom rules that apply to a products' 'sku-modifier'. Meaning I can add a sku modifier for the custom option, then create a shopping cart rule that has a condition containing that sku-modifier.

The only part left is to create an action that would eliminate tax. I can't simply add a discount that is the same amount as my tax rate since the tax rate varies by region.

I have poked around in \app\code\core\Mage\Rule\Model\Action\Abstract.php but I'm not sure how to go about adding the code that would enable this functionality. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.